# Bash capture stderr of a function while using trap

Tags: bash, trap

I have a function that will error in specific cases. I want to test the code I've written to see if it's erroring for those cases. For simplicity let's say the function is from a file with the following:

```
set -e
will_error() {
  echo "error" >&2
  exit 100
}
```

In my test file I want to be able to capture the output of the function `will_error` and compare it to what's expected to be printed to stderr if it was run for real.

```
test_no_default_no_argument() {
  trap ':' EXIT
  result=$(will_error 2>&1)
  if [ "$result" != "error" ];then
    echo "test failed"
    exit 1
  fi
}

test_no_default_no_argument
```

How do I capture the output of `will_error` and the return code to use for validation?

Comment: `output=$(trap 'will_error 2>&1' RETURN)` calls `trap` to set a trap and stores the output from doing so, but the command `trap` doesn't produce any output. The function `will_error()` is not called then the trap is set and so will produce output in future when the trap fires, not when it's set. [edit] your question to show what you're trying to do with the output of `will_error()` so we can help you.

Comment: So if `will_error` produces output at some later point, is it possible to capture the output of the `will_error` function?

Comment: As I said, [edit] your question to show what you're trying to do with the output of `will_error()` so we can help you. Please provide a [mcve] in every question you ask - in this case that'd be a small, complete script that includes the `will_error()` function plus the `trap` call but also whatever other code you need to cause the trap to fire (and so `will_error()` to be called and show us the output that produces today plus the output you WANT it to produce in future.

Comment: I edited the question to be more about capturing the `will_error` output as well as providing what I want to do with that output.

Comment: It's still not a [mcve]. There isn't a minimal, complete script in your question that we could copy/paste to execute as-is to reproduce whatever your current code does and try to enhance to do whatever you want it to do instead.

Comment: This certainly feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please make sure your examples are as close to the actual problem as possible, and don't let the desire not to impose make you ask a wrong, useless question.

Comment: [_grumbles about `set -e`_](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises)

Comment: Your code looks like it will do what you say you want it to do with respect to capturing the output of `will_error()`. [edit] your question to show what it outputs today and what you WANT it to output instead. To capture it's exit status just add `; ret="$?"` at the end of the same line as the call to `will_error()`. This is now a very different question from capturing the output of `will_error()` called from a trap as you showed previously by the way.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, while reading this code, why you feel the need to use a trap at all. (Or is that imposed by external constraints?)

Comment: ...note that `result_rc=0; result=$(will_error 2>&1) || result_rc=$?` will capture both `result` and the exit status of `will_error` and prevent errexit from firing regardless of whether you have it configured to otherwise be active within functions -- no trap-related magic needed. (See the "XY question" bit -- don't need to ask a question about traps if your _real goal_ is something where the better solutions don't require a trap in the first place).

Comment: I was looking to trap because of the `set -e` forcing the script to stop. I could remove `set -e` to fix it but I guess other areas of the code would need to be refactored to check the return code. Another option I could probably do is alias the exit command in this specific place to check but that's a bit unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why your example changed so much from when it was about using `trap 'will_error 2>&1' RETURN` but, in case you still have your original question, this is what I think you were originally trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

will_error() {
    echo "error" >&2
    return 100
}

foo() {
    trap 'output=$(will_error 2>&1); ret="$?"; trap - RETURN' RETURN
}

foo

printf 'output=%s\n' "$output"
printf 'ret=%s\n' "$ret"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
output=error
ret=100
```

[Don't use `set -e`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) but if you can't follow that advice then change the above code to this:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

will_error() {
    echo "error" >&2
    return 100
}

foo() {
    trap 'ret=0; output=$(will_error 2>&1) || ret="$?"; trap - RETURN' RETURN
}

foo

printf 'output=%s\n' "$output"
printf 'ret=%s\n' "$ret"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
output=error
ret=100
```